# Is it fine to mail the Associate Editor in his personal email provided in his homepage?

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

> Is it okay to mail an Associate Editor in his personal e-mail?

I have submitted a manuscript in a journal and I want to know the status of my manuscript.

The publisher of my journal is "World Scientific".
There is no option to mail the Associate Editor of the journal to whom I have assigned my manuscript.
Neither is any email address of the Associate Editor provided in the Journal Hoempage.Only his name and affiliation has been given.

Also there is only two templates of email address provided which are 
1.Extending Submission Deadline.
2.Extending Revision Deadline.

There is no template to ask about the status of the manuscript.

Is it fine to mail the Associate Editor in his personal email provided in his homepage?

Kindly comment.

Comment: Have you already contacted the journal office?

Comment: Follow the stated journal contact routes, they will give them even though you have not found them...

Comment: @Allure,I contacted them but I got no reply

Comment: @SolarMike;I dont know what are the journal contact routes,as I said in the question its not possible to type a different email other than the one typeset by them

Comment: @Learnmore Which journal is this? How did you attempt to contact the journal office? Which email did you write to (or did you use email at all)?

Comment: @Allure; the name is "Journal of Algebra & itts Applications",I tried to contact the journal office using the templates they have given but no reply came

Comment: What do you mean by "templates they have given"? Did you use https://www.worldscientific.com/page/contact-journal#jaa or write to jaa@wspc.com?

Comment: @Allure;I wrote to jaa@wspc.com, but I did not get a reply even after 1 week.Also there are 2 configured mails in their website which I referred as templates

Comment: The editor of that journal happens to be a friend of mine. I can ask her directly - how can I identify your email (e.g. what's your name, when did you send it, what did you write, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid doing that, except as a last resort. The person is likely to be confused (best) or offended (bad). Try to work first through the journal itself.

But also, it often takes quite a while for information about progress to filter through the system and it often takes quite a while for reviews themselves to be conducted.

If it just "wanting to know" for informational purposes, I recommend patience. If it is "needing to know" for some other purpose then you can press it, but, again, go to personal accounts only as a last resort.

You could, of course, ask the journal itself how to contact the editor and whether it is appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Its been over two months that my paper is under review,so I wanted to know the status,

Comment: I sent an email but got no reply from the journal.A I  said in the question its not possible to type a different email other than the one typeset by them

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not send stuff to journals with no route to ask questions?  Plus I don't know the publisher.  Sounds sketchy.  Why not IEEE or APS or the like?

I wouldn't ever contact the editor via personal channels.  He will want there to be a wall to separate admin stuff like you have.  I would pull the paper first.  Although even here sounds like you will have to use their awful contact system.